Macaronage issue: Batter doesn't shift to ribbons and goes dry
I used to make macarons until about January this year, when I moved about 10 mins away from where I used to live. No significant altitude change, no aircon in both places.
We had to get our oven replaced so I didn't make macarons for about 10 months.
I started again last month as I had an order to make and we had gotten the oven replaced about a month prior.
I do every step exactly as I used to and then I get to the Macaronage. It starts off well, my batter starts coming together but there's no gradual shift to ribbons. It just goes completely dry and I'm sitting there for 15 minutes trying to fix it.
Have I lost the ability to Macaronage or is there something environmentally wrong?

Is there a significant change in altitude or climate (humidity, temperature) or even something like air conditioning vs no A/C in the new place vs old.

@bob1 Climate, not so much as it's about 10 mins away from where I was. There might be a change in altitude but I can't be sure as to how significant. I used to live on the second floor of a 4 floor apartment. Now I live in a place where I can see my old apartment's roof if I stare hard enough. No aircon in both places.

Good to know no major changes.  You never know though - I could drive from my place at approx sea-level to about 800 m/2400 f in <10 min in my current location, with corresponding changes in climate and moisture levels.

I baked about 10 batches of macarons since posting the question. I tried changing my meringue (I usually use Swiss so I tried the more stable Italian), my macaronage technique (watched several videos and read books), my recipe (using less dry ingredients), changing the battery on my scale and now I'm convinced that it's my almond flour (I wanted it to be anything but this).
I used to buy my almond flour close to where I used to live but that place is a little too far out to get almond flour now, so I tried a new place that's closer to me. When sifting I noticed that it's a lot more chunkier so I go through more of it and keep the extra to maybe grind up one day for extra flour if I run out. I ran out and when I tried to grind it like I usually used to, it turned to paste almost immediately, meaning that it's a lot more oily than I originally thought.
According to a YouTube video I watched, this has the property of making your batter a lot thicker than intended and even overmixing doesn't solve the problem.
Looks like I'm going to have to take the longer drive to get my old almond flour again.

Thanks for following up; this was surprising and informative.

This might sound ridiculous to some, but you are living in a taller building.  Heat rises.  Where I live, my neighbor and I have our A/Cs set at about the same temperature.  Her apartment (second floor) is warmer than my apartment (first floor).  Is there any chance your home is warmer, maybe not by much, than your previous one?  Is the layout of your kitchen different?  Meaning you have to mix closer to your stove than you had to in the past?  I have never made macarons, but I have heard that little changes to air temperature can have an affect.
